# MAMP PRO : How to configure php SMTP mail setting in php.ini

Tags: php, email, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm new to MAMP and I'm trying to send mail from localhost(MAMP PRO), but I'm unable to send the mail from localhost. So can anybody list out the steps that help me to configure my MAMP PRO to send mail from localhost.

Note: I did follow some of the "solution" from google / stackoverflow, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: It seems that this question is just to general.

Comment: We need to know _what_ you've tried. Saying that you've tried something doesn't help us determine where you might have gone wrong if we don't know what it is that you've tried. My first Google search returned this result, which looks quite trivial. Have you tried this? What was the result? http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/how-to-sending-emails-with-mamp-pro.html

Comment: yeah. First i create a simple contact form using mail() function, after i submit the form, i din't received the email.
(note: i'm using GMAIL)